# How create a custom validator to SelectOneMenu?

Tags: primefaces, tooltip, validation, selectonemenu

I have a p:selectOneMenu and i want to validate the selectedItem. my code is:

```
<tooltip />
<p:selectOneMenu id="cardTypes" style="width: 150px" value="#{viewTrasactionsBean.transactionAhorroFiltroWrapper.tipoTarjeta}" required="true" requiredMessage="Debe seleccionar un Tipo de Tarjeta válido">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccionar..." itemValue="#{null}"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Todas" itemValue="ALL" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{viewTrasactionsBean.cardTypes}" var="types" itemLabel="#{types.descripcion}" itemValue="#{types.codigo}"/>
    <f:validator validatorId="cardTypesValidator"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:message for="cardTypes" display="tooltip"  />
```

The validator throw the ValidatorException, but for some reason, the tooltip (or the message) never shown.

I use Primefaces 4.0

Validator code:

```
@FacesValidator("cardTypesValidator")
public class CardTypesValidator implements Validator {

   @Override
   public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent c, Object o) throws ValidatorException          {
     throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error",  "ESTE ES EL ERROR"));
   }
}
```

Comment: can you show your code for your cardTypesValidator?

Comment: there is the code @VeenarM

Comment: remove display="tooltip" it's not a supported attribute for p:message as per the vdl, it may be causing it to break.